# Nodeunit with grunt can't find module 'tap'

Tags: node.js, requirejs, gruntjs, npm, nodeunit

So, armed with [this tutorial](http://sethlakowske.com/technology/sequelize-unit-testing-using-grunt-and-nodeunit/), I decided to add some unit testing to my node.js app. My gruntfile seems to be OK, and when I type `grunt nodeunit` my only test runs just fine, but after that, it crashes with error `Fatal error: Cannot find module 'tap'`:

```
$> grunt nodeunit
Running "nodeunit:all" (nodeunit) task
Testing db.test.js
.OK
Fatal error: Cannot find module 'tap'
```

I didn't know anything about this module, but after googliing it up, it seemed that it's something nodeunit would require. And indeed, there it is: `$MY_NODE_APP/node_modules/nodeunit/node_modules/tap` exists, and when I launch node in `$MY_NODE_APP/node_modules/nodeunit` and type `require('tap')` in interactive console, I get some object with a lot of stuff that gives me an impression that it works as it should.

So, the obvious question: why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        nodeunit: {
            all: ['./**/*.test.js']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');
};
```

*Update*: Installed `tap` to my project, but it didn't help too.

Comment: I received one close vote because of 'insufficient information'. What information should I add to the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue (well, this issue — it wasn't the last one) by installing the `tap` module manually.

Comment: Not a great solution. =/

Answer (score 7):

I landed on this question and have since resolved my own issue.  I'll post my resolution as it might be helpful to someone else:

*First the similarities:*

I was just getting my Gulp scripts setup, and I got this error when running my tests:

```
Fatal error: Cannot find module 'tap'
```

**Which didn't make sense because I wasn't using that library!**

*How I resolved:*

Turns out my paths were all kind of screwed up in my gulpfile.js. Therefore I was trying to unit test all of the modules in my node_modules folder!

Here's the new path:

```
 paths: {
      mocha: [
        '**/*.test.js',
        '!node_modules/**/*.js'
      ]
 }
```

Comment: I also had a similar problem with searching my ensure node_modules directory

Comment: Yup, I also fell into this; changed the directory structure and it worked straight away - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was inadvertently running the tests within the `node_modules` directory.  My `npm test` was `mocha **/*.test.js` and when I changed it to `mocha src/**/*.test.js` all of a sudden the message went away.  Makes sense really.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding another '*' right after "mocha" it is related to the folder's path so it may also fix the problem in other cases.